# Typescript issue with Parameters type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a very basic bit of TypeScript set up:

```js
class ClassOne<T extends (...args: any[]) => void> {
    callbacks = new Set<T>();
    add(cb: T) {
        this.callbacks.add(cb);
    }
    trigger(...args: Parameters<T>) {
        this.callbacks.forEach(cb => cb(...args));
    }
}

class ClassTwo<T extends Record<PropertyKey, (...args: any[]) => any>> {
    one = new ClassOne<(key: keyof T, ...args: Parameters<T[keyof T]>) => void>();
}
```

I would expect this to work, but TypeScript complains that:

```
Type '(key: keyof T, ...args: Parameters<T[keyof T]>) => void' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'key' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[key: keyof T, ...args: Parameters<T[keyof T]>]'.
      Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2344)
```

I cannot switch the signature to `(...args: any) => void` because then TypeScript complains that `Type 'Parameters<T>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.(2488)`. I also cannot use `T[keyof T]` on its own, because my `ClassOne` instance also needs to accept `key` as its first argument...

My question is: how could I set this up correctly, so that `ClassTwo` can have a `ClassOne` instance which has a function that can expand on any of `T`'s values?

I've looked all around the internet and experimented quite a bit myself, and I can't work it out...

Comment: Pretend you have a function that has the signature `(a, b, c) => d`. You pass this function to somewhere else that has the type `(...any[]) => void`. Is this safe? No. Your function could be called with 0 arguments or 1 argument. Since your function expects 3 arguments, this would probably break it. That is why TypeScript errors here.

Comment: A possible workaround (but I don't know if this'll break for you later on) would be to change the constraint to `T extends (...args: any) => void`, where the parameter type is now `any` instead of `any[]`, which is demonstrated [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QPIDsCmAeAKtVAPALqsgCYwAUAdFWAE4DmEAXNGMgJ4CU0AvAHzQA3APYBLYvwDeAKGizoxAK4BbJWzLAARs0xdpc-dGBDkEISFQUQQuuo0cA3DLkBfKa6mhIMeF8wB3ISwcAiJSaAAlVCMaYnQABRohAAdUGnw2AGlUNgAaaEpqeiYWdgBtAF0uPhK2XkknWWNUHmg0PzgECBQMAopaBmY42jAlVEIaCCxSgGtsoQAzaExy3ir+YTFeMgc3KSA).

Comment: Your workaround is correct, but runs into an issue with the rest of my code... I am updating the question so it is clear why I can't switch the signature to `(...args: any) => void`

Comment: Please show examples of what `ClassTwo`'s `one` property's `dummy` method should accept/reject. For your B question, it's possible `one = new ClassOne<T[keyof T]>();` is the solution, but without usage examples it's hard to know.  For your A question, it's that conditional generic types are hard for the compiler and unless you want a long technical explanation, I'd suggest removing A. Or removing B so that we can focus on the correct implementation.  While those two questions are related to the same code they are different, and SO really wants posts to ask a *single* well-defined question.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, updating it even further so the question is clearer.

Comment: You don't want `(key: keyof T, ...args: Parameters<T[keyof T]>) => void` because that will allow mismatches of key and args.  The thing you want is as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mp0Pxm), using the `any` workaround instead of `any[]` because that error is mostly a distraction from the typings.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not what am I missing?

Comment: That totally does answer my question! Thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maintain the connection between each key `K` of `T` and the corresponding parameters `Parameters<T[K]>`, you'll need to do something like this:

```
type MethodsToMadness<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any[]) => any>> =
  (...args: { [K in keyof T]: [key: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>] }[keyof T]) => void
```

Let's demonstrate that acting on an example `T`:

```
interface Foo {
  a(x: string): void;
  b(x: number): void
}
type FooMadness = MethodsToMadness<Foo>;
// type FooMadness = (...args: 
//  [key: "a", x: string] | 
//  [key: "b", x: number]
// ) => void
```

So `FooMadness` is a function with what looks like two call signatures; you can call it like a `(key: "a", x: string) => void` and you can also call it like a `(key: "b", x: number) => void`.  That is, it's similar to an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Now you can write `ClassTwo<T>` in terms of `MethodsToMadness<T>`:

```
class ClassTwo<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => any>> {
  one = new ClassOne<MethodsToMadness<T>>()
}
```

And this works from the caller's side:

```
const two = new ClassTwo<Foo>();
const one = two.one;
one.add((k, x) => console.log(k === "a" ? x.toUpperCase() : x.toFixed(2)));
one.trigger("b", 2) // "2.00"
one.trigger("a", "x") // "X"
```

The implementation of `ClassOne` does need to change a little because you still run into the error from your example with `any[]`.  I think you should just change to `any` which is less restrictive, and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) anywhere inside `ClassOne` that complains about it:

```
class ClassOne<T extends (...args: any) => void> {
  callbacks = new Set<T>();
  add(cb: T) {
    this.callbacks.add(cb);
  }
  trigger(...args: Parameters<T>) {
    this.callbacks.forEach(cb => cb(...args as any)); // assert
  }
}
```

(That assertion is to work around [ms/TS#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874).)

I don't want to go into a big digression about *why* the original doesn't work; it's essentially that `Parameters<T>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and when `T` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) then the compiler can't do much reasoning about it.  Conditional generic types are just too complex for it so you'll either get unsound or incomplete behavior depending on where and how the compiler gives up.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-uGgZuzGDSnD0EjKrVCS+yegv34MpZUlAkBg8ErmB0Qj2eEIJBgp3ONEuiLpT29yQYzF6xf+bEBAqsQjQXt0cAQEBQGGWHnNlu2HpJgLMOtZ52QYqddcnqD01agtfrttMYW3u-HCy0+DrFBvlhvHWCZDUEcHV6EIFQFBAQh0O+PDcFoobBtAAD82YUPgQgAKqzPMNCwJAqBmNAzC4LBQjciIuCoLYABMHCkc+aCwTEcQJGQGZZiRgzDMGREUAADKxwZSC+4rUYk4HPMGuDBlwjrBgAGsGQA)

Comment: This code causes a problem if the methods in `Foo` take different amounts of parameters, like here: https://tsplay.dev/ND8Y4N

Comment: Found a partial workaround for this (https://tsplay.dev/m0zZqw) but this seems quite uncomfortable... Is there some way to do this that will comfortably work with different amounts of parameters, or is that not possible?

Comment: All you have to do is mark `y` as optional as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wE8nyW).  If you have further questions please make a new post for it so that you're not depending on this post for updates.